# Why is my UpdateDE function in AMPscript not working?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, ampscript, dataextensions, automationstudio

I'm sending a mail using automation studio. In the mail content I included this line of AMPscript:

```
UpdateDE('Orders',1,'FactSalesHeaderSurrkey',FactSalesHeaderSurrkey,'InvoiceSentDate',NOW())
```

After sending, nothing has changed inside the data extension. I didn't find any errors in preview and the mail is sent succesfully.

I have no clue why the AMPscript is not working.

Comment: Based on FactSalesHeaderSurrkey  you need update InvoiceSentDate ?

Comment: Based on the code, I am assuming you want the InvoiceSentDate to be updated.  Is this showing as blank in the DE, even after preview/send or is there already an existing default value that is not changing?

Comment: That's correct. It is showing as blank in the DE. Before and after send.

Answer (score 0):

use like this

```
set @FactSalesHeaderSurrkey='somevalue'
  %%=UpdateDE('Orders',1,'FactSalesHeaderSurrkey',@FactSalesHeaderSurrkey,'InvoiceSentDate',NOW())=%%
```

based on this one `@FactSalesHeaderSurrkey` it will update